# rails 3 resources "without"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes

i want `resources :users` but without the `show` action. any way to do it in one line?

(something like `resources :users, :without => :show`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `:except`

```
resources :users, :except => :show
```